Jenkins publish over SSH fails to connect after upgrading Jenkins
I recently upgraded Jenkins from 2.46.2 to 2.426.3.
My config of Publish over SSH stopped working.
It uses password authentication.
I provided:

Name [DEV]
Hostname
Username
Password
Remote directory
Port (22)

When I click "Test Configuration", the error message is :
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [DEV]. Message [Algorithm negotiation fail: algorithmName="kex" jschProposal="curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com" serverProposal="diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"]]

Also, when I try to run SSH command ssh user@server in a Git-bash, I have this error:
no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

I believe it might be due to different versions of SSH on the client and server :

In Git-bash : OpenSSH_9.3p1, OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023
On destination server : OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
On Jenkins servers (main and agent) : OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

